# byte-buddy throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to instrument calls to the service() method of javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet using a Java agent based on Byte Buddy. The premain function in my code is called properly but instrumentation fails with the stack trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at     sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
  at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
    at ub.jagent.ServletInstrumentation.instrument(ServletInstrumentation.java:24)
    at ub.jagent.StackTracerAgent.premain(StackTracerAgent.java:75)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

I use the agent builder as follows:

```
AgentBuilder b = new AgentBuilder.Default().ignore(ElementMatchers.none())
        .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
        .with(AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE)
        .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)   
        .type(ElementMatchers.isSubTypeOf(HttpServlet.class))
            .transform((builder, type, classLoader) -> 
                builder.visit(Advice.to(ServletAdvice.class) 
                .on(ElementMatchers.named("service")
                .and(ElementMatchers.takesArgument(0, HttpServletRequest.class))
                .and(ElementMatchers.takesArgument(1, HttpServletResponse.class)))).installOn(inst);
```

And my Advice implementation looks like:

```
public class ServletAdvice {

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void before(@Advice.This Object obj,
                               @Advice.Argument(value = 0) HttpServletRequest a1,
                               @Advice.Argument(value = 1) HttpServletResponse a2,
                               @Advice.Origin Method method) 
        {
            System.out.println("\nRunning pre-method logic for " + obj.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ":" + method.getName() + "()");
        <...etc...>
        }
    }
}
```

Oddly, when I match on the specific Tomcat implementation class:

```
.type(ElementMatchers.named("org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer"))
```

...then agent setup works (although the references to HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in the Advice method trigger ClassNotFoundException during instrumentation itself).

Does this mean I have to include all the agent dependencies (including the Java Servlet API) in the agent .jar file itself?

I'm using ByteBuddy 1.6.2, Apache Tomcat v8.0.

**EDIT**
Revised and working code (with Rafael's help) looks like:

```
         .type(ElementMatchers.isSubTypeOf(new TypeDescription.Latent("javax.servlet.GenericServlet", Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.ABSTRACT, TypeDescription.Generic.OBJECT, null)))
         .transform(
                 new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                    .include(getClass().getClassLoader())
                    .advice(
                        ElementMatchers.named("service")
                            .and(ElementMatchers.takesArgument(0, ElementMatchers.named("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"))
                            .and(ElementMatchers.takesArgument(1, ElementMatchers.named( "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse")),
                        ServletAdvice.class.getName())
         );
```

Comment: I added an improvement to how you match the arguments. Currently, there is only such a matcher available for generic type parameters where you need to add `erausre` to the argument matchers but this is fixed in 1.6.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the servlet-family of types is not available to the class loader that Byte Buddy is using for resolving the advice. To overcome this, Byte Buddy offers a specific transformer that resolves the advice class for both the user's and the agent's class loader:

```
new AgentBuilder.Transformation.ForAdvice()
  .include(getClass().getClassLoader())
  .advice("your.pkg.ServletAdvice")
```

As for the element matchers, rather match the arguments' names then using the type constants.

Comment: Can this approach be used on regular interceptors? Or does it only apply to `Advice`?

Comment: Interceptors are not inlined, therefore they do not show these characteristics.